# 『30日でできるOS自作入門』をUSBからブートさせたい

Tags: assembly, usb, operating-system

かの有名なos自作本なのですが、同じようにつくるのはつまらないと思い、usbからブートさせようと思ってます
IPLは以下の通りです。その他は全部一緒です。lba方式でやったのですが、qemuで確認しようとした所、画面が一瞬瞬くだけで、osの本体が起動しません。下記のiplのどの部分に問題があるのでしょうか？また、本当に指定した位置にコピーされたかはどのように確認すればいいでしょうか？

```
  ORG 0x7c00
        ;; BPB Structure                                                                                                                     
JMP     entry           ;BS_jmpBoot                                                                                                  
BS_OEMName      DB "HARIBOTE"
BPB_BytsPerSec  DW 0x0200
BPB_SecPerClus  DB 0x01
BPB_RsvdSecCnt  DW 0x0020
BPB_NumFATs     DB 0x02
BPB_RootEntCnt  DW 0x0000
BPB_TotSec16    DW 0x0000
BPB_Media       DB 0xf8
BPB_FATSz16     DW 0x0000
BPB_SecPerTrk   DW 0x0001
BPB_NumHeads    DW 0x0001
BPB_HiDDSec     DD 0x00000000
BPB_TotSec32    DD 0x00ee5000
BPB_FATSz32     DD 0x00000020
BPB_ExtFlags    DW 0x0000
BPB_FSVer       DW 0x0000
BPB_RootClus    DD 0x00000002
BPB_FSInfo      DW 0x0001
BPB_BkBootSec   DW 0x0006
        times   12      DB 0    ;BPB_Reserverd                                                                                               
BS_DrvNum       DB 0x80
BS_Reserved1    DB 0x00
BS_BootSig      DB 0x29
BS_VolID        DD 0xa0a615c
BS_VolLab       DB "ISHIHA BOOT"
BS_FileSysType  DB "FAT32   "



entry:  

        MOV AX, 0 
        MOV DS, AX   
        MOV ES, AX
        MOV BX, AX
    MOV SP, 0x7c00
prepare:
        STI     ; BIOSがSTIし忘れていても大丈夫なために
            MOV     [drv],DL ; 起動ドライブ番号がDLに入っている(BIOSがDLに入れてからMBRを起動するので)
            CMP     DL,0x80
            JB      error    ; HDD系デバイスでなければエラー
            MOV     AH,0x41
            MOV     BX,0x55aa
            INT     0x13
            JC      error
            CMP     BX,0xaa55
            JNE     error
            TEST    CL,0x01
            JZ      error
readloop:
        MOV  CL, 0
retry:
        MOV DL, 0x80
        MOV AH, 0x42
        MOV SI, packet 
        INT 0x13
        JNC next
        ADD CL, 1
        MOV DL, 0x80 
        MOV AH, 0x00
        INT 0x13
        CMP CL, 6
        JAE error
        JMP retry
next:


        MOV AX,[bufferoff]  
        MOV BX,bufferoff  
        ADD AX,0x0200  
        MOV [BX],AX

        MOV AX,[blockNum]  
        MOV BX,blockNum  
        ADD AX,1  
        MOV [BX],AX

        CMP AX, 361
        JB readloop

        JMP 0xc200
error:
        MOV     SI,msg
putloop:
        MOV     AL,[SI]
        ADD     SI,1            
        CMP     AL,0
        JE      fin
        MOV     AH,0x0e         
        MOV     BX,15       
        INT     0x10           
        JMP     putloop


fin:
        HLT                     
        JMP     fin            
msg:
        DB      0x0a, 0x0a      
        DB      "load error"
        DB      0x0a            
        DB      0


drv:        DB     0x80
packet:  
packet_size:    DB 0x10          
reserved:       DB 0  
count:          DW 1     
bufferoff:      DW 0x0820      
bufferseg:      DW 0   
blockNum:       DD 1         
                DD 0  
RESB    0x01fe-($-$$)       
DB      0x55, 0xaa
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

手元で実験していないので的外れな回答かもしれませんが，

bufferoff:      DW 0x0820

で 0x8200 を指定していないのが気になりました．
http://oswiki.osask.jp/?(AT)BIOS によれば，ここに指定するのはオフセットなので，
セグメントセレクタのように勝手に 16 倍される，というようなことはないはずです．

最後に
JMP 0xc200
を実行していることからも，本当にやりたいのは
bufferoff:      DW 0x8200
なのではないでしょうか．

※qemu monitor という機能を使うとメモリの中身をダンプすることができますので，
　ディスクを読み終わった時点で永久ループさせておいてメモリダンプしてみると，
　読み込んでほしい位置にちゃんと読み込まれているか，チェックできますよ．

Comment: ありがとうございます。おかげ様で解決致しました。メモリでもしっかりと0x8000以降の番地に移動されてます。しかし、今度はqemu -usb usb.imgでjmp 0xc200しましたが、今度はos本体が動きません。なぜでしょうか？